# Laravel form sort of submitting in debug mode but doesn't work in normal mode

Tags: php, forms, postgresql, debugging, laravel

so I have a selection box that gives a dropdown menu to give messages a manager from the dropdown. It takes the input and then changes to a column in the database called manager for it's respective column. When I try to submit the selection menu it gives me the regular error for Laravel. But then when I put ?debug=1 at the end it submits but gives the row's manager column a value of just blank.

Here is what I have in the routes.php

```
Route::get('foo/{id}', 'fooController@bar');
Route::post('foo/{id}', 'fooController@bar');
```

This is the form.

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/admin/foo' . $message->id)) }}
{{ Form::select('handler[]', array('unassigned', 'foo', 'bar'), null, array('style' => 'width: 127px')); }}
{{ Form::submit('Change manager') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
{{ $message->manager }}
```

and here is what is in the fooController

```
public function bar($id = null)
{
    $message = Message::find($id);
    $handler = Input::get('handler[]');
    $message->manager = $handler;
    $message->save();
    return Redirect::action('AdminController@foo_bar');
}
```

I had a problem like this the other day, I have zero recollection of what I did. I really appreciate any help, thanks! The database is postgresql if that's any help

Comment: out of curiousity: where did you get `?debug=1` from? official docs?

Comment: Have you tried without the array form of handler? I.e. just using `{{Form::select('handler', ...)}}` and `Input::get('handler')`?

Comment: `?debug=1` does *not* turn the app into debug mode.

Comment: You have a route group with the admin prefix surrounding those two routes you showed us right?

Comment: @user3158900 yes I do.

Comment: @zwacky yeah sorry in my app.php I have 'debug' => $_GET['debug']

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I have this in my app.php 'debug' => $_GET['debug'

Comment: It looks like you are concatenating incorrectly and it's not giving you the right url.  Try `{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/admin/foo/' . $message->id)) }}`.

Comment: @user3158900 thanks, but that was only an error I made when changing the urls when posting on stack overflow. On my site it is concatenating correctly

Comment: @Mephoros yes I tried that, doesn't seem to make any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a `dd(Input::all())` at the beginning of your controller and make sure you're seeing what you expect.

Also since you're sending an array perhaps you have to do `Input::get('handler.0')` -- see [here](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#basic-input) right below the Input::only() and Input::except() code block.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem as though because you are naming your select `handler[]`, PHP is grabbing it as part of an array.

When setting up your message model, try this...

```
public function bar($id = null)
{
    $message = Message::find($id);
    $handler = Input::get('handler[]');
    $message->manager = $handler[0];
    $message->save();
    return Redirect::action('AdminController@foo_bar');
}
```

Usually, you'd only use names in your forms post-fixed with `[]` when you are accepting multiple values like checkboxes/multi-selects etc...  Otherwise, it's probably best to stick with not using it because it may cause confusion.

Comment: This still doesn't work. I also tried it with just handler. I know that it was getting this far before it was highlighting the line where it was $message->manager = $handler

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it in a almost frustratingly simple way by just changing the method to PUT.

like this

```
Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar', 'method' => 'put'))
```